# Maintain session for iframe in two different domain

Tags: asp.net, session, iframe

I have two domain names (all the sites are developed using ASP.NET):

- iframe.com
- domainA.com
- domainB.com

Both domainA.com and domainB.com have an iframe which point to iframe.com.

When I am browsing domainA, the iframe.com will set a session variables.

When I navigate to domainB (using the same browser and same session), I wish to maintain the session variables that I have set in iframe.com when I was browsing domainA.

Is this possible? I seems to lost all my session bariables :(

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Though I haven't tried, I think you can do it with sqlserver session mode..

Comment: Please use cookie for this.

Comment: @CodeSpread a cookie to store session information? Using client-side technology to store server-side data is extremely inefficient. All of the data stored in the cookie would have to travel from the client to the server and vice-versa for *every* request. With session stored on the server (In Process, SQL Server, etc.) the session remains on the server as it should and only the session id travels between the server and the client.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a custom version of the SQL Server Mode for session. In short, I would create an object (maybe a hashtable) and store its contents inside of the database, and then assign a GUID to it and send that GUID to the client to store as a cookie.

That way, every time the client (browser) sends the GUID from the cookie, you would look up that GUID in the DB and be able to fetch/store the data in SQL Server.